# Fastest way to compare and update milion rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of customers which I need to update and replace one column(varchar) with an id (integer). Let's call the first table Customers and the second Products
So, instead of having varchar (for example, Product A), I want to have an id of that product (foreign key). Products are in another table which have id and productName:

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE customers 
SET s_product = (SELECT id from products WHERE products.productName = customers.s_product)
```

But it takes looong time and I need a faster way to do this.
Also I've tried to set index on customers.s_product (BTREE and FULLTEXT), but still no improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create indices on both the tables as

> products(productName) &  customers(s_product)

And execute below query

```
UPDATE customers t1, products t2
    SET t1.s_product = t2.id
    WHERE t1.s_product = t2.productName;
```

Comment: I need an id, not the product name. So should it be
`SET t1.s_product = t2.id WHERE t1.s_product = t2.productName`

Comment: The query is running for an hour now. There is no speed improvement comparing to my query. :(

Comment: Is the table is being used by any running application? If so, there must be any locking issue with table. Just create a new table with the same data using query (create table customers_bk as select * from customers ) and try to update this new table

Comment: Can you please share the query plan for the query

Comment: Actually I solved it using the temporary table to insert  the compared data. However, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can try join statement here

`update customers as c join products as j on c.s_product = j.productName set c.s_product = j.id`

ref : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/